# set DataGridView ComboBoxColumn selectedIndex from DataGridView BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn has a datasource, which contains a list of names. 
DataGridView contains a separate datasource, which contains index for the list above.

Is there anyway for set the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn selectedIndex using datasource from DataGridView? 
As an example:

`var bs = new BindingSource() {DataSource =  objDatabase.GetDataTable("Traverse Table", )};
dgvTraverseTable.DataSource = bs;`

For "Traverse Tale" layout,

- 1/no
- 2/yes
- 3/no

dgvTraverseTable Columns:     colPathName (comboxboxcol),   colPathUse(checkboxcol)

For the colPathName, I have a BindingSource as a String List with

("PathNo1", "PathNo2", "PathNo3")

So Ideally, what should display is the following

- PathNo1 / no
- PathNo2 / yes
- PathNo3 / no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a complete working sample

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Datagridview_47080892
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        BindingList<BindedItem> dgvlist = new BindingList<BindedItem>();
        BindingList<comboItem> comboList = new BindingList<comboItem>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitDGV();
            AddData();
        }

        private void AddData()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                dgvlist.Add(new BindedItem
                {
                    prop1 = $"prop1value{i}",
                    prop2 = $"prop2value{i}",
                    prop3 = $"prop3value{i}",
                    prop4 = $"{i}"
                });
            }

            comboList.Add(new comboItem { showThis = "Make a selection", butTheValueIs = "0" });
            comboList.Add(new comboItem { showThis = "Option 1", butTheValueIs = "1" });
            comboList.Add(new comboItem { showThis = "Option 2", butTheValueIs = "2" });
            comboList.Add(new comboItem { showThis = "Option 3", butTheValueIs = "3" });
            comboList.Add(new comboItem { showThis = "Option 4", butTheValueIs = "4" });
            comboList.Add(new comboItem { showThis = "Option 5", butTheValueIs = "5" });
            comboList.Add(new comboItem { showThis = "Option 6", butTheValueIs = "6" });
            comboList.Add(new comboItem { showThis = "Option 7", butTheValueIs = "7" });
            comboList.Add(new comboItem { showThis = "Option 8", butTheValueIs = "8" });

        }

        private void InitDGV()
        {
            //dgv.Location = new Point(5, 5);
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()));
            dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()));
            dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()));

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbcol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cbcol.DataSource = comboList;
            cbcol.DisplayMember = "showThis";
            cbcol.ValueMember = "butTheValueIs";
            dgv.Columns.Add(cbcol);

            dgv.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "prop1";
            dgv.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "prop2";
            dgv.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "prop3";
            dgv.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "prop4";

            dgv.DataSource = dgvlist;
        }
    }


    public class BindedItem
    {
        public string prop1 { get; set; }
        public string prop2 { get; set; }
        public string prop3 { get; set; }
        public string prop4 { get; set; }
    }
    public class comboItem
    {
        public string showThis { get; set; }
        public string butTheValueIs { get; set; }
    }
}
```